# Codechef Q - Why am I getting a "Wrong Answer" error

Tags: c++, algorithm

**Question** - A Little Elephant from the Zoo of Lviv likes lucky numbers very much. Everybody knows that the lucky numbers are positive integers whose decimal representation contains only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not.

Let F4(X) be the number of digits 4 in the decimal representation of X, and F7(X) be the number of digits 7 in the decimal representation of X. For example, F4(456) = 1, F4(444) = 3, F7(1) = 0, F7(747) = 2. The Little Elephant wants to know the largest product F4(X) ∙ F7(X), where L ≤ X ≤ R. In other words he wants to know the value
max{F4(X) ∙ F7(X) : L ≤ X ≤ R}.

**1 <= L <= R <= 10<sup>18</sup>**

Example:
1) For the range, **1 100** answer will be 1 {47,74}

2) 4199 6000 answer will be 4 {4747, 4477}

I feel my code is correct, but on submitting it's getting the verdict Wrong Answer. Can anybody help me find out exactly what is going wrong?

My algorithm cannot be wrong (it's very straightforward). I've double checked the implementation (it handles all possible cases). It's difficult to believe that it's going wrong for some input.

Here's the C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char buf1[20],buf2[20];
int *L, *R, *ans, len, ansn;
bool flagL, flagR;

inline int count(int n)
{
    int a=0,c=0;
    for(;a<len;a++) if(ans[a] == n) c++;
    return c;
}
inline int max(int a, int b) { return a>b ? a:b; }
inline int min(int a, int b) { return a<b ? a:b; }

inline void f(int i, int n)
{
    int a=0,n4=0,n7=0,t;
    for(;a<=i;a++) if(ans[a] == 4) n4++; else if(ans[a] == 7) n7++;
    while(n)
    {
        if(n4 == n7)
        {
            n4 += n/2;
            n7 += (n-n/2);
            break;
        }
        else if(n4 > n7)
        {
            t = min(n,n4-n7);
            n -= t;
            n7 += t;
        }
        else if(n7 > n4)
        {
            t = min(n,n7-n4);
            n -= t;
            n4 += t;
        }
    }
    ansn = max(ansn,n4*n7);
}

void solve(int i, bool flagL, bool flagR)
{
    while(i<len)
    {
        if(flagL && !flagR)
        {
            if(4 > L[i])
            {
                f(i-1,len-i);
                return;
            }
                    if(4 == L[i])
            {
                ans[i] = 4;
                solve(i+1, 1, 0);
                ans[i] = 7;
                f(i,len-i-1);
                return;
            }
            if(7 > L[i])
            {
                ans[i] = 7;
                f(i,len-i-1);
                return;
            }
            if(7 == L[i])
            {
                ans[i] = 8;
                f(i,len-i-1);
                ans[i] = 7;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            // else
                ans[i] = 9;
                if(ans[i] > L[i])
                {
                    f(i,len-i-1);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
        }
        if(!flagL && flagR)
        {
            if(7 < R[i])
            {
                f(i-1,len-i);
                return;
            }
            if(7 == R[i])
            {
                ans[i] = 4;
                f(i,len-i-1);
                ans[i] = 7;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if(4 < R[i])
            {
                ans[i] = 4;
                f(i,len-i-1);
                return;
            }
            if(4 == R[i])
            {
                ans[i] = 3;
                f(i,len-i-1);
                ans[i] = 4;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            // else
                ans[i] = 0;
                if(ans[i] < R[i])
                {
                    f(i,len-i-1);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
        }
        if(flagL && flagR)
        {
            if(R[i] - L[i] == 1)
            {
                ans[i] = L[i];
                solve(i+1,1,0);
                ans[i]++;
                solve(i+1,0,1);
                return;
            }
            bool four = 4 > L[i] && 4 < R[i];
            bool sev = 7 > L[i] && 7 < R[i];
            if (four && sev)
            {
                f(i-1,len-i);
                return;
            }
            else if (four && !sev)
            {
                ans[i] = 4;
                f(i,len-i-1);
            }
            else if (!four && sev)
            {
                ans[i] = 7;
                f(i,len-i-1);
            }
            if (L[i] == 4 || L[i] == 7 || R[i] == 4 || R[i] == 7)
            {
                if(L[i] == R[i]) { ans[i] = L[i]; i++; continue; }

                if(L[i] == 4 && R[i] == 7)
                {
                    ans[i] = 4;
                    solve(i+1,1,0);
                    ans[i] = 7;
                    solve(i+1,0,1);
                    ans[i] = 5;
                    f(i,len-i-1);
                    return;
                }
                if(R[i] - L[i] >= 2)
                {
                    ans[i] = L[i]+1;
                    f(i,len-i-1);

                    if(L[i] == 4 || L[i] == 7)
                    {
                        ans[i] = L[i];
                        solve(i+1,1,0);
                    }
                    if(R[i] == 4 || R[i] == 7)
                    {
                        ans[i] = R[i];
                        solve(i+1,0,1);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (R[i] - L[i] >= 2)
                {
                    ans[i] = L[i]+1;
                    f(i,len-i-1);
                    return;
                }
                ans[i] = L[i];
            }
        }
        i++;
    } // end of while
    ansn = max(ansn, count(4)*count(7));
}

int main()
{
    int a,t; scanf("%d\n",&t);
    while(t--) // test cases
    {
        scanf("%s %s",&buf1,&buf2);
        len = strlen(buf2);
        L = new int[len];
        R = new int[len];
        ans = new int[len];
        for(a=0;a<len;a++) R[a] = buf2[a]-48;
        for(a=0;a<len-strlen(buf1);a++) L[a] = 0;
        int b=a;
        for(;a<len;a++) L[a] = buf1[a-b]-48;
        flagL = flagR = 1; ansn = 0;
        solve(0,1,1);
        printf("%d\n",ansn);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The algorithm:**

Firstly, put the digits of L,R in arrays L[],R[] of length = no. of digits in R. And initialize an array ans[] for keeping track of the answer integer (integer for which F4(ans)*F7(ans) is maximum).

Pad L by 0 on the left, to make it equal to R in length. (so 1,100 becomes 001,100)
This is done in main() itself, before making a call to solve()

The real logic:
Run a loop, for i in range(0,len(R))
For each i, compare L[i] and R[i]

Variables **flagL** and **flagR** tell you whether or not, you need to check L and R respectively.

Supposing the L[], R[] is initially:
238 967
First we need to check both of them starting from 0th index (hence solve(0,1,1) or solve(0,true,true) ).

Now 4 and 7 both fall **between** L[0] and R[0]. So any permutation of {4,7} can be put in the 3 digits, without ans[] going out of range **[L,R]**. So answer will be 2.

If the range would have been:
238 and 545

Only 4 would fall in **between** 2 and 5, so we shall put 4 in ans[0], and any permutation of {4,7} can be put in the remaining places. So answer is again 2.

What if the range is:
238 and 410

Neither 4 nor 7 fall in between L[0] and R[0]. 
But note that R[0] is 4.

So we shall now have 2 choices to put, 4 and L[0]+1 (this is where recursion comes in)

Why L[0]+1 ? Because if we put L[0]+1 in ans[0], ans[0] would fall in between L[0] and R[0] (for this R[0] - L[0] >= 2) and whatever we put in the remaining digits, ans[] would never go out of range. But we also have to check with ans[0] being 4. In the last example, it won't help, but it would if R was >= 477.

So the answer would be 1. (2 if R was >= 477)

Let's discuss another example:

Range: 4500 5700

Because R[0] and L[0] differ by only 1, we will have to check for both, once for ans[i] = L[i], then ans[i] = R[i] (or ans[i]++ )

Now if we check for ans[i] = 4, we won't have to compare ans[i] and R[i] anymore, since ans[0] < R[0], hence **ans** will always be < **R**. So we call solve() recursively like this: solve(i+1, true, false)

Next time, when ans[0] = R[0], then we won't have to compare ans with L (since ans > L, whatever we put in the remaining 2 places). Then we call solve() like this: solve(i+1, false, true).

You get the idea of how it's working, and also, if you look at my code, no possible test case is being left out. I don't know why I'm getting a WA.

---

PS: Andrew pointed out the mistake. The order of conditions was wrong. The if block `4 == L[i]` should have come before the if block `7 > L[i]`. Now the code works correctly.

Comment: I'd go through it and work it out on paper. You can follow the logic step by step and alert yourself when something is off. Use the same test case as what you run through your program, and at the same time run through with the debugger having a watch on the variables.

Comment: @Rushil you better copy and paste the question from the given link in this question body itself, so that this question remains valid even if the link goes dead

Comment: Here's a programming tip: if your code doesn't work the way it should, odds are that it's *your* fault. Don't automatically assume that your algorithm cannot possibly be wrong and therefore the code is correct because you think it's straightforward.

Comment: @Insilico My algorithm is surely correct, but I had a tough time implementing it. So the implementation could be wrong (although I can't figure out how!)

Comment: @Rushil: As chris has mentioned, try working it out on paper. Step through your own code manually and explain to another person what each line is doing.

Comment: @Rushil, your max and min can be replaced with the ones in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @chris I've tried for hundreds of inputs. I think I'll post an explanation of the code too, so it becomes easier for you guys to test the code

Comment: @Rushil, That's where the debugger comes in useful. As you go through, make sure the variables in the program match yours. At some point, they'll most likely differ.

Comment: @chris I have posted some explanation too, check it out.

Comment: You sure you didn't just get a "time limit exceeded" error?  Your algorithm does not appear very efficient and may just be taking too long.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y My algorithm is so efficient that it will work for integers of the order 10**10000 in almost no time. Just increase the size of array `buf1` and `buf2` (they should be equal). Currently it's 20, means it'll work for 10**19.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        if(7 > L[i]) // 7 > 4 ?
        {
            ans[i] = 7;
            f(i,len-i-1);
            return;
        }
        if(4 == L[i])  // how is this ever reachable?
        {
            ans[i] = 4;
            solve(i+1, 1, 0);
            ans[i] = 7;
            f(i,len-i-1);
            return;
        }
```

I think you mean:

```
-            if(7 > L[i])
+            if(7 < L[i])
```

Comment: The order is wrong, I've corrected the order of the `if` statements!
How come I didn't see that! Well thank you! This code works correctly!